# GridSearch returns different result than metrics.precision_score

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn

I have a quite simple text classification setup where i need to optimize the precision score. I use scikit-learn with a LinearSVC and a TfidfVectorizer. To find the optimal parameters, i use a GridSearchCV as in the [scikit-learn example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_digits.html).

My data set consists of 3400 text samples, from which 450 are labeled as 1. Therefore, i set the class_weight parameter of the SVM to 'auto', as is suggested in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) (it has been renamed to 'balanced' in the latest version of scikit).

```
training = load_training_data(some_file.json)

d_train = training['data']
d_test = training['target']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    d_train, d_test, test_size=0.33)

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

X_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(x_train)
X_test = vectorizer.transform(x_test)

param_grid = {
    'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
}

grid = GridSearchCV(
    LinearSVC(class_weight='auto'),
    param_grid=param_grid,
    scoring='precision',
    cv=5
)

grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = grid.predict(X_test)

print(grid.best_score_)                      # returns 0.829
print(metrics.precision_score(y_test, pred)) # returns 0.768
```

now from my understanding, shouldn't the last 2 values be the same? shouldn't grid.best_score_ return the best precision found and that should be equal to the precision_score calculated by the metrics module? The values actually differ quite a bit and i am still trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

grid.best_score_ is the result of cross-validation on train dataset while metrics.precision_score(y_test, pred) is calculated on the test dataset prediction.

Comment: That makes an awful lot of sense. I got confused by the cross-validation which internally uses train- and testing sets vs. my own train- and testing sets. Thanks!